# What concentration of HCl is safe to smell?

Tags: acid-base

I want to give students the chance to gently waft and smell HCl.

What concentration would be considered safe for a once-off single waft and smell ?

Comment: Why would you want your students to smell HCl?

Comment: See [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42178/what-chemical-compounds-used-in-qualitative-chemistry-can-be-distinguished-by-sm/42180#42180) and [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46332/testing-for-ammonia-by-smelling-it?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer. Bottom line: Don't smell chemical compounds. They are not perfumes.

Comment: That's not really answerable, thing is highly dependent on how you do it and what this "safe" means. BTW @NilayGhosh It's not like you can smell anything but chemical compounds ;>

Comment: @Mithoron It is late at night. I should catch some zzzs.

Comment: That will naturally occur if they are supposed to be trained in practical chemistry. If they don't, there are better things to smell.

Comment: Concentrated HCl solution is about 35% - 36%. Its odour is strongly corrosive and should not be smelled. In my school we consider that the aqueous mixture 1+1 has no odor. It is about 18% HCl.

Comment: I would rather let them see it, under a hood in a graduated cylinder.  Pour a small amount of the concentrated acid (37% works well) into the cylinder.  When the acid mixture evaporates the HCl molecules attract water vapor from the air and form a solution with reduced vapor pressure, so you see condensation.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is enough to watch the Safety Data Sheet to understand. I found this one browsing on the internet:

[Safety data sheet of a Chloridric acid manufacturer](http://biotech.bio5.org/sites/default/files/msds_hydrogen_chloride.pdf)

On section 11 you can find: ATE US (gases): 1560.000 ppmV/4h. ATE means "Acute Toxicity Estimates".

Answer (score 1):

As a teacher, you should *lead by example* how to engage with chemicals respectfully, as a professional. Which neither is to be fearful, nor to be sloppy and negligent for their *potential hazards*.  This includes to plan ahead, to limit exposure to dangerous goods (like concentrated HCl is), to use protective gear, safe manipulation of the chemicals in response to their *possible* action, and to have a rescue plan should something go wrong.

The students may already know the smell of acids from cuisine (e.g., balsamic vinegar, kimchi stew, choucroute garnie, etc.), but teach them early *the right way* chemists do:

[image]

(screen photo from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJXSLmYlvIQ); it is not concentrated HCl)

Or would you trust a dentist as professional if forceps were not both clean and functional?